# request.env['omniauth.auth'] is always nil when using seperate admin login using omniauth-identity gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, admin, omniauth

I want to use seperate admin login for my application using idenity provider.

I have written this in config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity, :model => Credential, :on_failed_registration =>SessionsController.action(:register)
  provider :identity, :model => Credential, :name => 'admin', :on_failed_registration =>      SessionsController.action(:login_admin)
  provider :google_oauth2, '000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com', '00000000000'
end
```

In config/routes.rb

```
 match '/auth/admin/callback', :to => 'sessions#authenticate_admin'
```

In app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
def authenticate_admin
  auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  session[:admin_user] = auth_hash['user_info']['email']
  if admin?
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    render :text => '401 Unauthorized', :status => 401
  end
end
```

But when i try to access request.env['omniauth.auth'], it always gets nil. While it is accessible when using default callback for normal users at sessison#create action. I just want to know if there is anything that has been missed in this code. I am following this blog http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/1/31/easy-rails-admin-login-with-google-apps-and-omniauth.